Showing that the classical groups are topological manifolds
I took a course in differential geometry last semester and I think I understood the basic theory of differential manifolds, but I recently read basic notions about topological manifolds and I’m trying to show that the classical groups $GL_n(K), Sl_n(K), O(n),U(n),SO(n)$ and $SU(n)$ (where $K$ is the field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) are topological manifolds, without using the fact that they are differential manifolds.
For $GL_n(K)$, I used the fact that if a matrix $A\in M_n(K)$ is such that $||A||<1$, then $Id-A$ is invertible. If I assume that $O(n)$ is a manifold, then I proved that $SO(n)$ is too, as a path-connected component of $O(n)$ (which is then open in $O(n)$). But for the rest, I am stuck for the moment, do you have any idea?
The method I know to show that they are differential manifolds used the fact that they are the preimage of a regular value of a certain function (like $A\mapsto A^\intercal A$ for $O(n)$).
And what would be a method for determining their dimension (which is the same as their dimension as differential manifold of course) directly ?
Also, if you have books or any kind of reference for this topic, I would be grateful!

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806696/proof-that-un-is-a-manifold and other questions which can be easily found via site search. Just enter "X manifold" for your favorite X. (Here it won't be just one duplicate since you have asked multiple questions at a time, which is not supported on this site by the way.)

It makes no sense at all to refuse to use tools of differential topology and to prove that these groups are topological manifolds.
